# Actionscript 3 Case statement with hitTestObject × 22461

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a nested MovieClip called theCar which has 6 elements inside it.
One of the elements is a transparent rectangle called hit.
theCar moves left and right to catch car parts using the keyboard keys.
What I want to achieve is a different view of the car depending on which object is caught. The catching of the car parts works correctly as objects[i] but using the code I have loses the hitbox and therefore no further catching occurs. Basically its just a different Catcher movieclip that I want to see. The idea is to build a complete car by adding caught parts. So I have thehitTest for a caught object. So if objects[I] = 2 then the engine will be added. if objects[I] =3 the left wing etc etc.

```
if (objects[i].hitTestObject(theCar.hit )) 

{

 //Scores for the Hits
 switch (object1)
 {
 case "[2]":
 score = 2;
 //change viewed object to carpl which shows the car plus engine
 //Movieclip theCar.carpl.view;
 stage.addChild(theCar.getChildAt(1));
 break;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clear. And format the code a bit. I personally don't understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement does not evaluate the ordinal index of the objects array.

Instead, it would be by object instance:

```
switch (object1)
{
    case object[2]:
        /* ... */
        break;
}
```